# Unable to call stored procedure with FromSql in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to call a stored procedure from EF Core, and am running into an error I don't know how to solve.

**Class:**

```
public class PlayerOverview
{
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public int World { get; set; }
    public string Alliance { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Castles { get; set; }
    public int Cities { get; set; }
}
```

**Query:**

```
    _context.Set<PlayerOverview>()
            .FromSql($"CALL usp_player_overview('{player}')")
            .Select(pl => new
            {
                Player = pl.Player,
                World = pl.World,
                Alliance = pl.Alliance,
                Score = pl.Score,
                Castles = pl.Castles,
                Cities = pl.Cities
            });
```

**The Exception:**

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot create a DbSet for 'PlayerOverview'
>   because this type is not included in the model for the context.

How can I include this class in the model for the context? If I add a `DbSet<PlayerOverview>` I get a different exception complaining about a lack of primary key for the set.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a DbSet, and define a primary key, as there are no columns called Id or PalyerOverviewId, EF is unable to guess which column is the key. So use either the [Key] attribute or the fluent api (or simply add a unique PlayerOverviewId to your result and model:

```
[Key]
public string Player { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

Comment: Adding the class to DbSet (even if it's not in the database - ours rarely return the table itself) enables both _context.Set<PlayerOverview>().FromSql(query) and _context.PlayerOverview.FromSql(query). Thanks!